# "Цель урока такова: научиться решать уравнения." Каким членом предложения является инфинитив "научиться"?

Tags: синтаксис, члены-предложения

> Цель урока такова: научиться решать уравнения.

Каким членом предложения является инфинитив "научиться"?

Answer (score 1):

**Цель урока такова: научиться решать уравнения.**

Инфинитив ***научиться*** не является членом предложения, так как входит в обособленную конструкцию, раскрывающую содержание местоименного сказуемого. Можно сказать, что мы имеем **обособленный оборот на основе инфинитива, поясняющий сказуемое.**

**Примечание.** Обособленные члены не являются членами предложения и не образуют  словосочетания с подчиняющим словом. С предложением они связаны полупредикативной связью.

**Выбор знака (тире или двоеточие):** http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=119#pp119

При отсутствии пояснительного союза вместо запятой перед пояснительным членом предложения часто ставится тире... Возможна также постановка двоеточия...

**Для сравнения:**

1) Цель урока другая —  научиться решать уравнения. Постановка тире перед пояснительным оборотом.

2)  Цель урока  — научиться решать уравнения. Тире между подлежащим и составным именным сказуемым (именной частью является инфинитив).

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Приведите, пожалуйста, ссылку на какой-нибудь источник, что обособленные члены не являются членами предложения.

Comment: У меня вузовский учебник (2013 год), его нет в Сети в электронном виде, а информация оттуда. Возможно, кто-нибудь еще может помочь Вам определиться в этом вопросе. Как видите, на форуме представлены разные мнения, и проголосовали не за мой ответ Я не могу исключить, что  другие участники Вам скажут, что обособленные члены  являются членами предложения.

Comment: Jasmin, а что за "вузовский учебник" у Вас? Дайте угадаю... КУСТОВА? Тогда у меня вопрос к Вам: к примеру, нужно ли при разборе подчеркивать как определение причастный **оборот**? Или же, в случае его обособления, он членом предложения не является?

Comment: Нет, в моем учебнике вообще нет разборов. Как и что подчеркивать - это, наверное, школьная тема.  Надеюсь, Вы поможете автору вопроса. Я думала, что эта тема разбирается в Корпусной грамматике, но, кажется, нет. Неужели у нас нет нормального академического  справочника по грамматике в режиме онлайн ? У Розенталя был учебник "Современный русский язык", но я его видела только на бумажном носителе. А без ссылок трудно работать, что ясно видно из ситуации с этим вопросом. Нет ссылок - нет ответа, у меня теперь такое представление о форуме.

Comment: @Jasmin, скажите, пожалуйста, авторов и название учебника.

Comment: И скажите, пожалуйста, различаете ли вы полупредикативные и пояснительные обособленные обороты?

Comment: Г.И. Кустова "Синтаксис современного русского языка". Курс лекций для студентов вузов по специальности "русский язык и литература." Структура статей у нее такая.  Осложненное предложение: однородные члены, обособленные члены, вводные и вставные конструкции. Обособленные члены: (1) полупредикативные, (2) пояснение и уточнение, выделение, присоединение. Получается, что надо различать. Но особо выделяются присоединительные конструкции (это могут быть любые обороты в простом  предложении, а также отдельное предложение в сложном предложении).

Comment: Спасибо. На ваш взгляд, в данном случае "Цель урока такова: научиться решать уравнения." какой тип связи: пояснительный или полупредикативный?

Comment: Это явное пояснение, раскрытие содержания местоименного слова. У Кустовой пояснение основано на логических отношениях тождества и связано  с повторным наименованием  (расшифровкой) уже названного ранее (предмета, признака, действия).

Comment: Я согласен с Вами. Поправьте, пожалуйста, ответ на вопрос, где упоминается полупредикативная связь.

Comment: Посмотрев источник, я не нашел точного упоминания о том, что обособленные члены не являются членами предложения. Наоборот, в разделе о полупредикативности говорится о том, что "обособленными могут быть определения (в том числе приложения) и обстоятельства". Разъясните, пожалуйста, ваше мнение.

Comment: Разъясняю. Я, пожалуй, неточно выразилась, поэтому цитирую: "Обособленные члены не являются присловными распространителями, то есть не образуют словосочетания с подчиняющим словом."  Обособленные члены не вписываются в структуру основного предложения, отделены семантически и интонационно. Из правил школьного разбора мы видим, что обособленные члены могут являться оборотами, то есть могут иметь зависимые слова. Вся эта структура является обособленным членом и подчеркивается как единое целое.  Весь оборот - это член предложения (определение, обстоятельство и др.), но обособленный член.

Comment: Не являются членами предложения только вводные предложения и вставные конструкции.

Comment: Тогда обособленный оборот "научиться решать уравнения" является тем же членом предложения, что и поясняемый член, т. е. сказуемым?

Comment: Вы когда-нибудь слышали выражение "обособленное сказуемое или подлежащее"? Думаю, что так не говорят. Если уж "сказуемое" обособилось, то не быть ему предикативной основой предложения.  Главные члены не обособляются.  А как же тогда говорить? Вернемся к моему ответу. Там сказано об инфинитивном обороте, поясняющем сказуемое. А когда обособляется подлежащее, то его называют обособленным приложением.

Comment: Тогда если "оборот - это член предложения", то какой в данном случае? Определение?

Comment: Какой - не знаю, но не определение. Попробуйте задать обществу этот вопрос о ПОЯСНИТЕЛЬНЫХ членах, может быть, они одобрят "обособленное пояснительное сказуемое и подлежащее" и представят для этого убедительные доказательства. Приведите несколько примеров с разными знаками, вроде этих. Цель была одна — до рассвета дойти до леса;Настроение одно: скорее добраться до дома....случилось одно очень важное для них обоих событие, именно встреча Кити с Вронским  (союзное пояснение подлежащего). Я считаю, что это обороты, поясняющие сказуемое или подлежащее, других названий нет. Но это мое мнение.

Answer (score 1):

> ***Цель урока такова: научиться решать уравнения.***
>
> Каким членом предложения является инфинитив "научиться"?

Предложение — **сложное бессоюзное пояснительного типа**. Вторая его часть раскрывает указательное местоимение *таков*, играющее роль сказуемого в первой части.

Почему предлагаю такую характеристику?

Аналогичное предложение разбиралось когда-то Розенталем и Добромысловым в книге *"Трудные вопросы грамматики и правописания"* (М., 1960):

> ***Вывод был таков: идти по пути русских.***
>
> Такие предложения относятся к числу бессоюзных сложных пояснительного
>   типа.

Как разбирать вторую часть?

Наверное, так же, как и в таком, к примеру, предложении:

*Чтобы **научиться решать уравнения**, не обязательно решать их в огромном количестве.*

Как охарактеризовать здесь придаточное? Инфинитивное предложение? Безличное?

Но как бы его ни назвать, ***научиться*** в нем будет сказуемым,  ***решать*** — дополнением:

***научиться*** (чему?) ***решать***…

Comment: 1) ЛОПАТИН  и его современный академический справочник (не 1960 год): http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=123#pp123 Примечание. В подобных случаях при более подчеркнутом пояснении может употребляться и двоеточие: Все они [письма] о главном: перестройке в нашей жизни (газ.); НАСТРОЕНИЕ ОДНО: СКОРЕЕ ДОБРАТЬСЯ ДО ДОМА (газ.). По-моему, тот же тип предложений.  2) Как определить вид предложения. Есть интересный способ: берем словосочетание, додумываем предикативную основу, и вот уже  у нас двусоставное предложение.  И это при том,  что содержание неполных предложений определяется по тексту.

Comment: Еще одно замечание. Возьмем пояснительную конструкцию из сборника Розенталя: Мне угодно только одно — предостеречь вас (Ч.);http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=119#pp119.  При большом желании я и это предложение могу назвать БСП, тире в таких предложениях тоже ставится: Мне угодно только одно —  (я хочу) предостеречь вас

Answer (score 0):

Это сложное предложение, бессоюзное, состоит из двух простых. Предложения связаны по смыслу и разделяются двоеточием, т.к. второе предложение поясняет первое. Основа первого предложения - цель такова, основа второго - научиться решать. Таким образом, оба инфинитива (научиться решать) входят в состав составного глагольного сказуемого в простом безличном предложении (подлежащее  в таком предложении не мыслится).

Comment: Научиться решать задачи - это словосочетание, а не предложение.  Односоставные инфинитивные предложения выглядят иначе. В них действие   подразумевает субъекта действия, который выражается сущ. в Д.п. или определяется из ситуации. Инфин. предложения выражают различные экспрессивные и модальные значения. Тебе ходить. Здесь не проехать. Что делать? Чтобы сдать экзамен, надо подготовиться.  Или такое: Вот бы научиться решать задачи! Или еще проще: Научиться решать задачи! Немедленно! Предложение всегда предполагает ситуацию (время, наклонение) в отличие от словосочетания с его назывной функцией.

Comment: И по поводу составного глагольного сказуемого. Является ли глагол учиться/научиться модальным? Хотя его значение близко к модальному, в перечне модальных глаголов он обычно не значится. Я учусь (чему? что делать?)  решать задачи. Здесь модальности нет,  так откуда она появится в форме совершенного вида. Я научился решать - я умею решать: семантика сходная, но грамматические формы разные.